# Whats the difference between void function(stuct *s) vs void function(stuct s)?

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, structure

I have this school homework to do and I'm confused because of the functions I am asked to make. It is different from the style I do singly-linked list.

I do singly linked-list like this:

```
typedef struct structNode{
    int data;
    struct structNode *next;
} node;

typedef struct structList{
    int count;
    struct structNode *head, *tail;
} list;

void insertFront(list *L, int x);
void insertRear(list *L, int x);
void insertAt(list *L, int x, int p);
void deleteFront(list *L);
void deleteRear(list *L);
void deleteAt(list *L, int p);
void displayAll(list *L);
```

Where all arguments are receiving a pointer but my homework needs me to do my code like this:

```
typedef struct node *nodePtr;

struct node {
    int item;
    nodePtr next;
};

typedef nodePtr Statistician;

Statistician newStatistician();
  //allocates memory to the structure. Dynamic allocation
void destroyStatistician(Statistician *s);
  //destroys statistician
void add(Statistician s, int x);
  //Adds data to the rear
void remove(Statistician s, int x);
 //removes data
void displayData(Statistician s);
```

So I'm confused whats the difference because I'm used to receiving pointers and the homework style is different.

I think the one with the receiving pointer is call by reference thats why what ever i edit locally can be edited globally...

And also how is my structure implementation different from the one I have to do?

Comment: You need to read up on what `typedef struct node *nodePtr;` means. Check https://cdecl.org/ .

Comment: The symbol `Statistician` is a type-name, an alias for the type-name `nodePtr`, which in turn is an alias for the type `struct node *`. So `Statistician` *is* a pointer type. For e.g. `add` the argument `s` *is* a pointer. This very clearly shows the dangers of defining aliases of pointer types: It makes code unclear and harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: @Jezreel Tan  I am sure that this declaration void add(Statistician s, int x); is wrong. Instead it should look like void add(Statistician *s, int x);

Comment: @Jezreel Tan : The rational for this exercise to introduce [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).   A user's Statistician.h file of these would **not** include `struct node {
    int item;
    nodePtr next;
};` - it is not needed _there_. The goal is to  make `Statistician` an [opaque pointer type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistician is a pointer. It is typedef'ed as nodePtr which in turn is defined as node*. So passing a Statistician is really passing a node*.

Whether it's smart from a usability standpoint to make a pointer look like a nonpointer is a different question.

Comment: "Whether it's smart ... is a different question" I would argue that the answer is no. And I think this question is a good example of why the answer is no.

Comment: Ofcourse it's not, it is just a headache on your part. Every time you alloc ate memory or anything or pass it to function, you have to look into the header for knowing what it exactly is.

Comment: Incidentally, could you add something to your answer to explain why the argument to `destroyStatistician` is a pointer to a `Statistician`  even though `Statistician` is already a pointer.

Comment: Very true. The only reason I could think of to typedef a pointer is if you were using C++ `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, but then again those are not "really" pointers. Besides, typedef'ing is there increase readability and maintainability. Typedef'ing a pointer so you don't have to write a `*` is like the laziest thing you could ever do and is straight up confusing and counterproductive.